# Looking for a modern fairy-tale in which a prince goes on "impossible" quests for a princess, but ends up marrying a witch who helped him

Tags: identification-request, folk-tales

I'm looking for a story (almost certainly a modern author working in a fairy-tale motif, rather than an actual folk tale) in which a prince is given a sequence of "impossible" tasks by a princess he is courting, e.g., "bring me a dress made of sunshine" (not sure if this is an exact quote). After completing a series of such tasks, he decides not to marry the princess, but instead marries the witch or sorceress who helped him with the tasks.

The story was in a collection of other stories (not sure if single or multiple authors for the collection), and in a public library in the US by the early 1990s.

Comment: Hi RLH and Wecome to LitSE. There's already some good detail in your question, and you may have reviewed it already, but can you have a look through the [identification request wiki](https://literature.stackexchange.com/tags/identification-request/info) and add any detail you remember about those questions too? Even small details, like the colour of the cover, can help.

Comment: @AdamBurke Added one more location detail

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Prince Amilec* by Tanith Lee

[isfdb.org](https://isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1165818) synopsis:

> Prince Amilec turns to a witch for help in completing the tasks set
> for him by the princess he wishes to marry.

From the [Jud's Creative Writing Medley](https://judsjottings.wordpress.com/tag/prince-amilec/) review:

> The reader has recognized almost immediately that the witch is far
> more suitable a bride for Amilec, and must wait in frustration until
> the ‘turn’ occurs, when he will realize this for himself.  Hope is
> raised when the princess demanded a wedding dress:
>
> By this time Amilec was getting a bit fed up with her tantrums, but he
> thought that, of all her demands, this was the most reasonable.  (
> Zipes, (1986) p. 53)
>
> When the witch delivered the dress, wearing it to display its beauty,
> he was stunned – ‘the scales fell from his eyes’.  In front of the
> court he declared:
>
> “How can I have been so blind!  You are the most beautiful girl I have
> ever met.  You are also the kindest.  May I humbly ask you to be my
> wife?  I promise to look after Basil, and I’ll live in the cave, if it
> will make things easier.”  (Ibid, p. 54)

Comment: Thanks! This is almost certainly what we’re looking for, and I’ll come back and accept once we’ve confirmed.